# Перемещение узла в al-tree (adjacency list) mysql

Tags: mysql, дерево

```
CREATE TABLE `al_tree12` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `parent_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(100) default NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `fk_tree_treeeee` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tree_treeeee` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES 
`al_tree12` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Имеется такая структура,где путь у корня null, а у остальных- путь от корня до узла, подскажите, как в mysql перенести узел (сменить родителя)

Comment: Видимо изменить поле parent_id у наследника. Потому что именно оно указывает на его родителя

Comment: @Mike, но ведь тогда нарушится структура дерева и не учтутся дочерние узлы, я, наверное, недостаточно полно сформулировала вопрос, корректнее будет сказать: перенести ветку

Comment: Вся ветка перенесется. дочерние узлы при этом трогать не надо, их же непосредственный родитель останется тем же самым

Comment: @Mike, видимо плохо разобралась со структурой дерева в бд, спасибо